# C# WPF PrintDialog. All pages have same background

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I trying to print list of canvases. Every content is good (text, rectangle...) only images are wrong. 
I have 2 canvases: 
[image: Canvas 1]
[image: Canvas 2]

Final result of print to pdf:
[image: PDF Result]

Background of page 1 is good, but there is missing image.In page 2 is wrong background and missing image.

My code to print:

```
    PrintDialog prnt = new PrintDialog();

    if (prnt.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
        document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(
        1920,
        1080);

            FixedPage page1 = new FixedPage();
            page1.Width = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
            page1.Height = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;

            page1.Children.Add(can1); //can1 - is canvas
            PageContent pageContent1 = new PageContent();
            ((IAddChild)pageContent1).AddChild(page1);
            document.Pages.Add(pageContent1);

            FixedPage page2 = new FixedPage();
            page2.Width = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
            page2.Height = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;

            page2.Children.Add(can2); //can2 - is canvas
            PageContent pageContent2 = new PageContent();
            ((IAddChild)pageContent2).AddChild(page2);
            document.Pages.Add(pageContent2);

        prnt.PrintDocument(document.DocumentPaginator, "Document");
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: [This post may help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456208/printing-a-wpf-visual-containing-images)

Comment: A partially solved problem. Thanks anyway. But I have another problem. If image has no effect everything is good. But if I use Drop Shadow Effect or Blur Effect image is not printed.

Comment: Then I think you have to switch to another solution: maybe you can do a screenshot of your application, and print the result. [See this post for screenshot method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837286/wpf-take-a-screenshot-and-save-it). The screenshot method capture the rendered pixel, so should get what you want.

Comment: Yes... it's good solution but partial... If I export to pdf I can copy text etc. With this solution this will be only image. Canvas: https://imgur.com/NPuniMw

New PDF Result: https://imgur.com/a/bNxTW

Comment: Every effect will ignore control render (Blur, drop shadow effect). Not only images, all controls with effect are ignored.